# How to get the content of an html file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to retrieve the code from an HTML file in PHP.

And display it in a textarea.

Example: if I have a file with a div and a foo h1 in it I want my textarea to appear like this.

After a few hours of research, I can't find a good result.

[Here is my sample html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnjeS.png)

And I want this html file to be readable in a textara that I styled.

[Example right here of stylized file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyyfi.png)

Thank you in advance for your lights !

[Exemple result display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Cy9.png)

I tried to use fopen in order to be able to open the file and read it but I cannot convert my string into an html tag.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "_but I cannot convert my string into an html tag_"? How/where/why would you need your string to be converted to an HTML tag? Can you post the code you already have?

Comment: I want to be able to modify an HTML file (a header for example), in a textarea, in order to be able to give access to my company's professions to be autonomous on the subject.

And I wish to make it readable from a a textarea that I styled.

Comment: And what doesn't work? Basically, it's echo `<textarea>; echo $theContentsOfYourFile; echo </textarea>`. That _should_ be it. Any errors on your side? Blank page?

Comment: Indeed normally it should be a classic echo, to display the text content, but it does not display the tags.

Example in my file:

<div>
 <h1> Toto </1>
</div>

This will get me into my Toto textarea.

I am looking to have the code with the tags and not the text.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [readfile()](https://www.php.net/readfile):

```
readfile("/path/to/file");
```

This will read the file and send it to the browser in one command. This is essentially the same as:

```
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/file");
```

except that [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) may cause the script to crash for large files, while readfile() won't.

Comment: Hello thankx for the response, but im testing and not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your can try using jQuery, below is the example code:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

**OR**

Reference link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: Hello thankx for response, indeed it works well but it shows me the text and not the tags.

Comment: For tag display you need to add the HTML entities in your HTML. Check this link: https://devpractical.com/display-html-tags-as-plain-text/